# Convert a String into a Variable

Tags: c#, string, debugging, variables

This might not be possible but it would be hugely helpful with debugging. Sometimes random bugs occur when the program is running. I'd like to be able to type something in (a string) and then it would grab a variable with the name of that string and return its value.

```
int mainNumber = 89;
```

Input: retrieve mainNumber
Output: 89

Is something like that possible? I don't want to have to create debugs for every single variable I have on the off chance something could go wrong. I know I could wait for the bug to occur, stop the program, throw a debug in and wait again, but this would be faster.

Comment: Bugs are never random - they occur for a specific reason(s).  Determining what those reasons are can be a pain, but there's no such thing as a random bug (IMO).

Comment: When you say "debug", do you mean "breakpoint"?

Comment: OK, fine. Bugs aren't random. I know they happen for a reason. -_- And yeah I'm using visual studio. The problem is the bugs happen when its not in testing but when it's in the field. So I can't really use visual studio when it's a running exe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to learn about the [`variable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dt5w8ta.aspx), [`watch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx) and [`immediate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) windows of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Would the 'immediate window' be what you're looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading up on Trace and Debug in .NET.  You can typically switch [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) and [Debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx) statements off and on from a program's config file, thus not affecting your runtime performance unless you want these dumps.  Then you can sprinkle `Trace.Write(...)` and `Debug.Write(...)` statements in your code to provide the output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you're going to need to do some research.  Here are some things to consider/try:

1. What is the bug?  Is an exception being thrown, is data not coming back correctly, etc.  Identify what it is that you're trying to root cause.
2. Do you know under what circumstances the bug happens?  Since you said random, chances are you don't yet know the answer to that.
3. Are you able to reproduce or see the bug in a test environment?

One option that I've done in the past is to add logging (usually to a text file) to the application in question.  I put in logging in the areas of interest, and timestamp the entries.  Grab enough information so you can adequately identify the actions that are occurring (before/after states of variables/objects, any supporting information that identifies the action, etc).

When a bug is reported (or reproduced), if the reporter gives enough information (i.e., time, what they were doing, other things particular to the app or what they were doing) you can look in your log files and see what was going on.

Once you have that information, you can either identify the root cause, or narrow it down to a more specific area and focus your efforts there.

It can be something of an iterative process, depending on how big the app is and how large the area of possible problems can be.

Comment: Honestly, it was a simple yes or no question. I know what bugs are. I know how they develop. I know methods of logging and finding them. There was no particular situation that I was relating this to. I just thought this would be an easier way to deal with them in the future. If no such thing exists, then we can drop it here. I don't need coaching. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem.  You did ask if there was a better way (before you edited your question) :)

Comment: That was my mistake. I thought I'd get answers to something similar to that, like a special method call or debug windows (which doesn't really help), and not Programming 101. lol